# Can't find GPS Location

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a singelton thread-class that sends the gps point to my server. The class holds and refresh the gps position.

FinderThread:

```
public class FinderThread extends Thread {
    private static FinderThread SINGLETON;
    public boolean isinterrupt = true;
    public int maxage;
    public int minage;
    public int distance;
    public String gender;
    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;
    public String sid;
    public Context ctx;
    LocationManager gps;
    boolean nav;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    private Handler dlh;
    private Handler myLocationHandler;
    boolean pause=false;




    private FinderThread(Context ctx,Handler dlh, Handler myLocationHandler) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        gps = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gps.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,60000, 20, llistener);

        pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("NFF", 0);
        sid = pref.getString("sid", "");

        this.dlh = dlh;

        if (myLocationHandler!=null)
        {
            this.myLocationHandler = myLocationHandler;
        }
        if(myLocationHandler != null)
        {
            myLocationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    }
    public static synchronized FinderThread getInstance(Context ctx,Handler dlh, Handler myLocationHandler) 
    {
         if (SINGLETON == null) // falls null 
         { 
               SINGLETON = new FinderThread (ctx,dlh,myLocationHandler);//instanzieren 
         }
         else
         {
             SINGLETON.myLocationHandler= myLocationHandler;
             SINGLETON.dlh = dlh;
             myLocationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
         }
         return SINGLETON;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        if(SINGLETON != null)
        {
            SINGLETON.start();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void pause()
    {
        if(SINGLETON.getState()==State.RUNNABLE || SINGLETON.getState()==State.WAITING)
        {
                SINGLETON.pause = true;

        }
    }
    public synchronized void tcontinue ()
    {
        if(SINGLETON.getState()==State.RUNNABLE || SINGLETON.getState()==State.WAITING)
        {
                SINGLETON.pause = false;

        }
    }
    public synchronized boolean isPaused()
    {
        return SINGLETON.pause;
    }
    */

    public synchronized void pause()
    {
        this.pause = true;
    }
    public synchronized boolean isPaused()
    {
        return this.pause;
    }
    public synchronized void tcontinue ()
    {
                this.pause = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        //Location lastpoint = gps.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

        //longitude = String.valueOf(lastpoint.getLongitude());
        //latitude = String.valueOf(lastpoint.getLatitude());

        try
        {
            while (isinterrupt) {
                if(!pause)
                {
                    Log.e("NFF", "Finder Thread Begin");
                    RestConnection r = new RestConnection("finder", dlh, "POST");
                    r.setParameter("minage", String.valueOf(minage));
                    r.setParameter("maxage", String.valueOf(maxage));
                    r.setParameter("distance", String.valueOf(distance));
                    r.setParameter("gender", String.valueOf(gender));
                    r.setParameter("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
                    r.setParameter("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                    r.setParameter("sid", sid);
                    Log.e("NFF Finder Paramater", String.valueOf(minage)+" "+String.valueOf(maxage)+" "+String.valueOf(distance)+" "+String.valueOf(gender) + " "+String.valueOf(latitude)+" " +String.valueOf(longitude)+ " " + sid  );

                    r.start();
                }

                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("NFF FT", "InterruptedException");
            isinterrupt = false;
        }
    }
    private LocationListener llistener = new LocationListener (){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())!= null)
            {
                latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                longitude =  String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                if(myLocationHandler != null)
                {
                    myLocationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e("NFF", "GPS Disabled");
            isinterrupt = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e("NFF", "GPS Enabled");

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    public void saveProperties ()
    {
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("maxage", maxage);
        editor.putInt("minage", minage);
        editor.putInt("distance", distance);
        editor.putString("gender", gender);
        editor.putString("lat", latitude);
        editor.putString("long", longitude);
        editor.commit();

    }
    public void loadProperties ()
    {
        maxage = pref.getInt("maxage", -1);
        minage = pref.getInt("minage", -1);
        distance = pref.getInt("distance", -1);
        gender = pref.getString("gender", "f");
        latitude = pref.getString("lat", "f");
        longitude = pref.getString("long", "f");
    }
    public synchronized void pushSettings()
    {
        SINGLETON.maxage = maxage;
        SINGLETON.minage = minage;
        SINGLETON.distance = distance;
        SINGLETON.gender = gender;
        SINGLETON.latitude = latitude;
        SINGLETON.longitude = longitude;
    }




}
```

When i test my app on the emulator and set the position with the emulator control everthing work fine. When i test it on my phone, the droid don't find the position. I have testet the app "GPS Test", there it finds the position within 3 minutes with 5 sattelites.

Please help

Comment: are you testing it outdoors or inside?,because gps doesn't work indoors.

Comment: outdoor --> i wrote that the app "gps test" found the location

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the time between notifications and the distance required to trigger a notification?

Comment: i only start the FinderThread when it has a position. An the notification (in the notificationbar) is only shown to notice the user the the thread is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure looks like you have everything there.

You give yourself the permission in the manifest for FINE_LOCATION, right?

The one suggestion I would make is change your `requestLocationUpdates()` so that it requests fixes with 0 time between them and 0 distance between them.  All GPS recievers I have seen will give you fixes about once a second with this setting, which is pretty much how most gps engines work.  Just on the off-chance that the one-minute and 20 m you put in your request are screwing you up.  If you get fixes with this suggestion, you can work from there to minimize amount of time gps is on.

Good luck!